# Can an administrator spy on your iPhone just by setting up a Microsoft Exchange account?

Tags: exchange, activesync

I was told recently that an administrator can gain access to all of your text messages and call records, just by simply setting up ActiveSync for Microsoft Exchange on your personal iPhone.  Is this possible?  I know that administrators have this ability for a company-issued blackberry, but is there a way to do this on a personal iPhone?

I know for sure that ActiveSync policies can control various features on the iPhone, as I've had a passcode enforced, and I've actually had my camera feature disappear because of policy.  But what else can be controlled?

I've scoured the net to find information about the subject, but I haven't found much anything.

Thanks,

Comment: See the [Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf) for details about what the administrator can do.

Comment: Why use your personal iPhone with the business if they're not compensating you for it? I'd rather not risk legal issues by risking mixing personal and business equipment like that and personally I'd be miffed at someone (myself, employer) if my personal phone had features "managed" when I'm footing the bill.

Comment: In addition to what Bart stated, they can't access your iPhone if you don't configure it to connect to the corporate Exchange server. If this is your personal iPhone then don't configure it to connect to your corporate Exchange server. If this is a company issued iPhone then by rights they can and should have complete access to the device and any and all communications to and from the device.

Answer (score 3):

No an administrator can't access you text messages and call record.

Supported Exchange/ActiveSync policies on iPhone are described in [iPhone Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf)
Enterprise can also use a `profile distribution service`, this allow enterprise to push policies to the iPhone remotely. These policies can almost force any settings of the iPhone. See the [PDF](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf) for details